# Can Mysql Innodb handle heavy parallel processing

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a Mysql system with a table of 1.7M records. This is a production system. It was previously Myisam & very resilient but as a test I have converted it to Innodb (and the php script) in the hope that it would run faster and row-level locking would make it even more resilient. It is serviced by 30 robots using PHP 7 CLI. Each of them scans the table for records that need to be updated, updates them then continues as part of the team until the job is done. They do this in chunks of 40 rows which means the script is run about 42,500 times.

But during testing I have noticed some features of Innodb transactions that I had not expected and seem to be showstoppers. Before I roll it back I thought I'd ask others of their views, whether I've completely got something wrong or to prove or disprove my findings. The issue centres around one db call (all search fields are indexed) below is pseudo-code:

```
update table set busy=$token where condition=true order by id $order limit $units
if affected rows != $units
do function to clear
return
else do stuff.....
endif
```

BEFORE
Under Myisam the result is that the robots each take a run at getting table level locks and just queue until they get them. This can produce bottlenecks but all are resolved within a minute.

AFTER
Under Innodb the call is ok for one robot but any attempt at multi-user working results in 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'. 
Changing the wait_timeout / autocommit / tx_isolation makes no difference. Nor does converting this to a transaction and using:

```
begin
select .... for update
update 
test
commit or rollback
```

It seems to me that:

1 Innodb creates an implicit transaction for all updates even if you don't set up a transaction. If these take too long then parallel processing is not possible.

2 Much more importantly,when Innodb locks rows it does not 'know' which rows it locked. You can't do:

```
begin
select 10 rows where condition=this for update
update the rows I locked
commit
```

You have to do two identical calls like this:

```
begin
select 10 rows where condition=this for update
update 10 rows where condition=this
commit
```

This is a recipe for deadlocks as robot1 may lock 40 rows, robot2 locks 40 others and so on but then robot1 then updates 40 rows which may be completely different from the ones it just locked. This will continue until all rows are locked and they cannot write back to the table.

So where I have 30 robots contending for chunks of rows that need updating it seems to me that Innodb is useless for my purposes. It is clever but not clever enough to handle heavy parallel processing.

Any thoughts...

Comment: "when Innodb locks rows it does not 'know' which rows it locked" is only true if you do not have a good index for it. It locks all rows (plus maybe gaps) it needs to look at when executing the query. Check the execution plan for e.g. a filesort, a full table scan or something similar (and/or add it to the question in addition to the index and the query that you assume fit together). Check if you enabled autocommit mode, it commits after every statement. It will act like `update.... commit ... test ... commit`, NOT like `update... test ... commit` as in your pseudo code. (But so does MyISAM).

Comment: Start your test again, and run "show engine innodb status" before your timeouts.  That will give you lots of information about what's currently happening.

Comment: "run about 42,500 times" -- per what?  per fortnight?

Comment: In your sample code, where is the `BEGIN`?  Or are you running with `autocommit=0`?

Comment: How much time does "do stuff" take?  Are the robots continually running?  Do you have 30 CPU cores?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Newer versions can handle higher concurrency.)  Is the Query cache turned off?  (I hope so.)

Comment: You didn't describe how robots divide up the work. Surely you assigned non-overlapping rows to them, yes?

Comment: Thanks for comments so far. Kevin: I do use show engine innodb status as well as show full processlist & also select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks and lastly htop. So monitoring during testing is ok.

Comment: Mysql ver is 5.7.19. Have inserted 'begin' in my OP. Please assume that's what I meant. System is Linux, 3 machines update database over 7 days each month. They run continually. Will check query cache.

Comment: Update
Have resolved the first part - 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'. I was wrong, it can be tweaked. Did my sums again - worst possible case seemed to be 10 minutes so I doubled this and set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1200. Also refined the search criteria to reduce searches and this seems to be sorted - No more errors. 
What remains is my question about innodb 'knowing' which rows it has locked.

Answer (score 0):

Ponder this approach:

```
SET autocommit = 1;
Restart:
$left_off = 0;
Loop:
  # grab one item:
  BEGIN;
    $id = SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE condition AND id > $left_off
             ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
    if nothing returned, you are end of table, COMMIT and GOTO Restart
    UPDATE tbl SET busy = $token WHERE id = $id;
  COMMIT;
  do stuff
  UPDATE tbl SET busy = $free WHERE id = $id;  -- Release it
  $left_off = $id;
Goto Loop
```

Notes:

- It seems that the only reason to set `busy` is if "do stuff" hangs onto the row "too long".  Am I correct?
- I chose to lock only one at a time -- less complexity.
- `$left_off` is to avoid scanning over lots of rows again and again.  No, `OFFSET` is not a viable alternative.
- `BEGIN` overrides autocommit.  So that transaction lasts until `COMMIT`.
- The second `UPDATE` is run with autocommit=1, so it is a transaction unto itself.

Be sure to tailor the number of robots -- too few = too slow; too many = too much contention.  It is hard to predict the optimal value.

Comment: Rick, Yes 'do stuff' may take a few minutes so I need the record locked during that time.  However, I do need robots to be able to lock 40 records at a time. So your approach would not fit my needs.

I have resolved this by hiving off the relevant columns from the main table and putting them in a much thinner relational table. So now:

 each robot locks and marks relevant rows in this 'thin' table
 it holds the ids of the 40 rows it has locked in an array
 parses through them in a loop
 writes back updates to the main table and clears the locks in the thin table during a transaction

Answer (score 0):

During my tests of Innodb v MyIsam I found that when I did resolve any contention issues the Innodb model was 40% slower than MyIsam. But, I do believe that with further tweaking this can be reduced so that it runs on a par with MyIsam.

What I did notice that MyIsam would queue 'waiting for table-level lock' indefinately which actually suited me but punished the hard disk. Whereas Innodb is a much more democratic process and the disk access is more even. I have rolled it back for the moment but will pursue the Innodb version in a few weeks with the adjustments I commented on above.

In answer to my own question: Yes Innodb can handle heavy parallel processing with a lot of tweaking and rationalizing your database design. Dissapointing that no one answered my question about whether Innodb record locking has an awareness of which records it locks.

Comment: It gets a bit subtle about when it locks "gaps" (between rows) and, hence, locks more rows than it needs to.